# Deprecated `Buffer` in Jimp breaking AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, jimp

I am writing an image resize lambda function.  It reads an object from s3 and uses `jimp` to resize it.  When I run it, I get this error:

```
ERROR   (node:9) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
```

I have traced this down to the `jimp` in `image.scaleToFit()`.  I don't get this error when running locally.  Both are running node 14.  I am assuming this is particular to AWS Lambda.

My failing code:

```
    const { Body } = s3Result;  //body is a buffer
    const jimpImage = await Jimp.read(Body).then((image) => {
      
      // debug tells me the bug happens here
      let imageResult = image.scaleToFit(width, height)

      imageResult = imageResult.quality(
        quality
      );
      return imageResult.getBufferAsync("image/jpg");
    });
```

Is there a workaround to this issue so I can keep using `jimp`?

Alternatives are welcome in the comments.

Thank you

Comment: Having the same or similar issue, the Jimp.read in Lambda fails when reading from a buffer.